# (Beginner) Spectators at a football match

Tags: functions, finance

I know this is a very simple problem, compared to most of what is posted here.
I have a math assignment about functions, which I am terrible at. 
One of the questions in particular buggers me:

''A football club charges a fee of 75€ for a ticket every football match. Every football match the club expenses 75,000€ (fixed cost), and it is estimated to expense 15€ for each spectator. Let x be the number of spectators to the match.''

For clarification, the revenue of each football match will be 75€ per ticket purchased. The costs will be 15€ per attendee + a fixed cost (a cost which doesn't change per attendee) of 75000€.

On to the problem that I can't figure out:

Determine for the profit h(x) as a linear function of the number of spectators

This seems really simple to me, however, I cannot figure out the function I'm supposed to write... I'd some help with this.

There's another problem which frustrates me. It is a follow-up to this question: 'how many tickets should the club sell, to avoid a financial problem'. A financial problem is when costs exceed revenue. To calculate that, I used the following equation:
$75x = 15x + 75,000$, with the result that the club should sell 1250 tickets to avoid a financial problem.

What I can't figure out, is the next question:
Unfortunately, the number of spectators decreases, and it is hard to maintain the club without increasing the membership fee. The club manager says there are, on average, 1000 spectators each time. How much should be the new membership fee to avoid a financial problem?

I am utterly clueless as to what to do to answer this, and so would like some help.

I am sorry if this is not how I am supposed to formulate or set up any questions. It is my first post on here. I am sorry if I wrote way too much, but I was unsure as to how I should shorten it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can represent profit, P, with the basic profit formula: $P =$ **Total Revenue - Cost of Goods Sold.**

Let's start with the Total Revenue as function of $x$, the number of spectators for a match. Since,

> A football club charges a fee of 75€ for a ticket every football match

Our only source of revenue are the tickets sold, leaving us with a revenue equation: **Total Revenue for a given match** = $75x$

Now the costs are mentioned here:

> Every football match the club expenses 75,000€ (fixed cost), and it is estimated to expense 15€ for each spectator.

Meaning the total cost is the fixed cost plus the variable cost, that varies according to $x$, which is the number of spectators at given match. This results in the following $$Total Cost = 75000 + 15x$$

Returning to the original profit formula, we can replace Total Revenue and Cost of Goods Sold (fancy way of saying Total Cost) with our equations, resulting in the following: $$P(x) = 75x - (75000+15x)$$ or $$P(x) = 60x - 75000$$

To find your break-even point, set profit = $0$ and solve for $x$. This will tell you the minimum number of spectators that must attend in order to break even.

You should have enough now to answer the rest of the questions.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you think you could help me with the other question as well? ''Unfortunately, the number of spectators decreases, and it is hard to maintain the club without increasing the membership fee. The club manager says there are, on average, 1000 spectators each time. How much should be the new membership fee to avoid a financial problem?''

This is actually the problem I am having the most difficulty with.

Comment: @OscarHildebrandt So in this case, the Revenue equation wouldn't be the same right? You can't charge people 75 euros anymore because it is too low. Therefore, represent the new cost per ticket as \alpha$x$ and solve for \alpha by replacing it in the original profit equation: $$P(x) = \alphax - (75000 + 15x)$$ where $x = 1000$ and you are looking for the break even point again.

Comment: I am slightly embarrassed to admit that I still have trouble doing this. I do not know what you mean by alpha? Is it just another variable, or is it a coefficient? I am sorry for these noobish questions, but I really would like to understand this fully. Thanks!

Comment: Apologies, I messed up the syntax. Yes alpha is just a dummy variable acting as a placeholder that you need to solve for.

Comment: OK, I have to give up. I do not see how I can solve this. Thanks so much for your help, though!

Comment: Using my last equation. Set P=0 , x=1000 and solve for alpha. HINT: the anewer is 60

Comment: The answer is 60? But if there's a 1000 spectators, the revenue will only be 60000€, which is less than the fixed cost.

Comment: Using your method, I found the answer to be 90. I did it by $0=1000x-(15x1000+75000)$ Is my answer correct?

Comment: Jesus my bad again. The new price needs to be 90 per ticket. Hope you can solve it and prove why.

Comment: Ok, I got it now. Thank you so much!!!!